# Formatted text fetched from MongoDB doesn't display properly in HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm web scraping with puppeteer but the [description](https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/job-listing/2021-six-month-analytics-sales-internship-german-speakers-bloomberg-JV_IC2671300_KO0,57_KE58,67.htm?jl=3817829945&pos=102&ao=1044074&s=149&guid=0000017a43c318beb033de30567e6437&src=GD_JOB_AD&t=SRFJ&vt=w&uido=A07C859157E656FE734518C723EC904C&cs=1_70d0d4a1&cb=1624634497327&jobListingId=3817829945&ctt=1624634509511) I'm getting has different text formats i.e. h1, bullet points, etc.

I scrape the text using `$("#JobDescriptionContainer").html();`, it is then saved on MongoDB, but when I get it to my JS/React app, the text is not formatted (everything is in one plain string).

How can I illustrate the scraped text in the original format (as shown on the site I scraped) on my website?

I would like: [image]

But I have: [image]

Comment: I think, You need to set data as innerHTML once you got it from DB.
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: mDBData}} />;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set data as innerHTML once you got it from DB.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: mDBData}} />;
```